# Python pandas: Need to know how many people have met two criteria

Tags: python, pandas

With this data set I want to know the people (id) who have made payments for both types a and b. Want to create a subset of data with the people who have made both a and b payments. (this is just an example set of data, one I'm using is much larger)

I've tried grouping by the id then making subset of data where type.len >= 2. Then tried creating another subset based on conditions df.loc[(df.type == 'a') & (df.type == 'b')]. I thought if I grouped by the id first then ran that df.loc code it would work but it doesn't.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: groupby id and count unique type. If count > 1 then you have that subset

Comment: also can you please share cleartext instead of an image. It makes it easy for us to extract that and provide you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the dataframe into two, one with type a payments and the other with type b payments, then merge them,

```
df_typea = df[(df['type'] == 'a')]
df_typeb = df[(df['type'] == 'b')]

df_merge = pd.merge(df_typea, df_typeb, how = 'outer', on = ['id', 'id'], suffixes  =('_a', '_b'))
```

This will create a separate column for each payment type.

Now, you can find the ids for which both payments have been made,

```
df_payments = df_merge[(df_merge['type_a'] == 'a') & (df_merge['type_b'] == 'b')]
```

Note that this will create two records for items similar to that of id 9, for which there is more than two payments. I am assuming that you simply want to check if any payments of type 'a' and 'b' have been made for each id. In this case, you can simply drop any duplicates,

```
df_payments_no_duplicates = df_payments['id'].drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

You first split your DataFrame into two DataFrames:

- one with type a payments only
- one with type b payments only

You then join both DataFrames on id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to solve this problem.  This first time, group by id and type and then you can group again to see if the id had both types.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"id" : [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], 'payment' : [10, 15, 5, 20, 35, 30, 10, 20], 'type' : ['a', 'b', 'a','a','a','a','b', 'a']})

df_group = df.groupby(['id', 'type']).nunique()

#print(df_group)
'''
            payment
id  type         
1  a           1
   b           1
2  a           1
3  a           1
4  a           2
5  a           1
   b           1
'''

# if the value in this series is 2, the id has both a and b
data = df_group.groupby('id').size()

#print(data)
'''
id
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    2
dtype: int64
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use groupby and nunique to get the count of unique payment types done.

```
print (df.groupby('id')['type'].agg(['nunique']))
```

This will give you:

```
id         
1         2
2         1
3         1
4         1
5         1
6         2
7         1
8         1
9         2
```

If you want to list out only the rows that had both `a` and `b` types.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby('id')['type'].transform('nunique')

print (df[df['count'] > 1])
```

By using groupby.transform, each row will be populated with the unique count value. Then you can use count > 1 to filter out the rows that have both `a` and `b`.

This will give you:

```
    id  payment type  count
0    1       10    a      2
1    1       15    b      2
7    6       10    b      2
8    6       15    a      2
11   9       35    a      2
12   9       30    a      2
13   9       10    b      2
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use the length of the returned set for the given id for column 'type':

```
len(set(df[df['id']==1]['type'])) # returns 2

len(set(df[df['id']==2]['type'])) # returns 1
```

Thus, the following would give you an answer to your question

```
paid_both = []
for i in set(df['id']):
    if len(set(df[df['id']==i]['type'])) == 2:
        paid_both.append(i)

## paid_both = [1,6,9] #the id's who paid both
```

You could then iterate through the unique id values to return the results for all ids. If 2 is returned, then the people have made payments for both types (a) and (b).

Comment: OP is looking to find all the ids that have both `a` and `b` types. With this, the result is a 1 or 2. That may not help OP

Comment: added for loop to show how it works for OP